# PHP, регулярные выражения. Как отрезать часть ссылки после домена?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Написал программу.

```
<?php
if  (is_file ('text.txt'))
{
    $text = file_get_contents('text.txt');
    $output = '<style> a.redhref {
        color: red;
}</style>';
}
 else
{
     die('Not found');
}
$pattern = '/((https?):\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\S]*)*\/?/i';
$replacement = '<a href="$0" class= "redhref">$0</a>';
$text=preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $text);
$output .= $text;
echo $output;
```

Она берёт текст из файла и находит URL. Делает их ссылками и делает ссылки красного цвета. Надо сделать так, чтобы ссылки были красивыми(читабельными) на выводе. Пример: ссылка на `http://www.google.com/?param=test&jkbk%343%435376878chbkblnjl`, а надо чтобы в тексте выводило только `www.google.com`, но при нажатии на неё переходило по полной ссылке. Как реализовать? Желательно использовать регулярные выражения.

Comment: И почему "желательно регулярные выражения". Есть специализированная функция http://php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php которая вам даст компоненты адреса, а вы из них можете составить все. что угодно

Comment: если именно регулярные надо использовать то `$replacement = '<a href="$0" class= "redhref">$1</a>';`

Comment: @JarryRoxwell а что вообще значит $0 и $1?

Comment: на примере: `str="f5."; $pattern = '/(\w)(\d)(\.)/i';` соответственно в `$0` будет `f5.`, в `$1` будет `f`, в `$2` будет `5` и так далее.
Называется это ссылки на подмаски.

Comment: @JarryRoxwell хорошее решение, спасибо большое.

Comment: @JarryRoxwell, ещё один вопрос. У меня допустим URL `http://www.google.com`. Почему `$1` это `http://`, а `http` это $2?

Comment: @ПавелКушнеревич `((https?):\/\/)` первая скобка это `$1` вложенная `$2`

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58741/discussion-between-jarry-roxwell-and--).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно и без регулярных, вот так:

```
<?
  $link = '';
  $long_link = "http://www.google.com/hello/?param=test&jkbk%343%435376878chbkblnjl";
  $split_link = parse_url($long_link);
  $link = trim($split_link['host'].$split_link['path'],'/');
  $output = "<a href='$long_link' class= 'redhref'>$link</a>";
```